# Changing the name of JibX CodeGen generated classes

Tags: java, jibx

I have several files that I have created using the CodeGen tool provided by JibX. These classes all have the same root name and thus the generated classes all have the same name.

I initially resolved this issue by placing all of these generated classes into their own package to resolve naming collisions. I then ran into the problem of needing to declare the entire package name, which is quite long, every time I wanted to declare or caste a new object.

My original idea to handle this was to create an empty subclass with a distinct name that extended the original auto-generated class. Such as

```
public class AutoGen
{
     //This class generated by CodeGen binds as expected
     //No problems marshalling or unmarshalling documents
}


public class UniqueName extends com.CompanyName.ProductName.SDK.Events.HeartBeatEvent.AutoGen
{
     //This class is empty
}
```

The problem I am running into now is that JibX will not marshall or unmarshall strings or files to this subclass due to a lack of a binding.

After reading through the CodeGen documentation again I can not seem to find a command that will allow me to declare what the generated class name should be. Is there a way to efficiently make the classes generated by CodeGen have unique names declared by the user? If not is there a way to make JibX marshall and unmarshall the subclass correctly? Either of these solutions will work.

It is also important that I mention that I **can't** alter the xsd files that the code is being generated from.

Answer (score 0):

An option that you have is making the generated classes unique, put them into whatever package structure that you would like then go and edit the bindings.

Since you cannot change the XSD and I would assume that you don't want to write the corresponding classes manually, this option may be the best for you.

To answer your question directly, there is no way that I know of to specify the name of the generated classes. Instead you should name the classes uniquely yourself and then edit the binding configuration so that it corresponds to the new names and package structure.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the JiBX name-converter extension documented on this page:

http://jibx.sourceforge.net/fromschema/codegen-extends.html

If you can't use the options available in the default implementation you can write your own name converter.

You will probably have to write a custom converter. It should be pretty simple.

You will find the JiBX source code here:

https://github.com/jibx/core

Good luck!

Don Corley
JiBX contributor